# Transform list of data frames to one data frame with df names in extra column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, stack, rbind

I would like to transform a list of data frames to one big data frame. The problem is, that I only have the list and not the separate data frames. An additional column with the names of data frames and without the rownames should be included in the new data frame.

Here's what I tried:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = c(1.1,2.0,3.5), y = c(4.1,5.1,6.3))
d2 <- data.frame(x = c(3.3,2.7,1.9,2.9,1.9),y = c(6.4,5.2,2.4,3.0,5.1))
d3 <- data.frame(x = c(3.4,2.7,1.8,0.2),y = c(6.2,5.0,4.1,0.5))

my.list <- list(green = d1, blue = d2, yellow = d3)
```

The target data frame should look like this:

```
target.df <- data.frame(colour = c(rep("green",nrow(d1)), rep("blue", nrow(d2)), rep("yellow", nrow(d3))), 
                        x = c(1.1,2.0,3.5, 3.3,2.7,1.9,2.9,1.9, 3.4,2.7,1.8,0.2),
                        y = c(4.1,5.1,6.3, 6.4,5.2,2.4,3.0,5.1, 6.2,5.0,4.1,0.5)
                        )
```

The code

```
my.df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, my.list)
```

produces a dataframe with row names from the names of data frames instead of an extra column.

I tried this:

```
new.df <- stack(my.list)
```

But there is `Error in stack.default(my.list) : at least one vector element is required`

How can I produce the target data frame?

Comment: @Sotos: This is not a duplicate, because I want to create a data frame out of a LIST. In your related question the starting points are data frames, not a list!

Comment: Yes it is a duplicated. Try any solution on your list. If you see the question it starts with data frames that are then put in a list! The answer you accepted is the same as one of the answers in the dupe

Comment: Ok. But the solution provided by akrun is very simple and effective...

Comment: The same one exists in the dupe as well. Give it a read and tou will find a lot of simple answers in there

Comment: `library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, VAR, sep='\\s+')` is not the same as `do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, colour = names(my.list), my.list)))`. The answer to this question here doesn't use the package tidyr. It uses rbind, unname, Map ... The answer `mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d+")) %>% map_df(I, .id = "src")` is much more complicated than the answer provided here.

Comment: yes it is working. but I still like the FIRST solution from akrun: `do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, colour = names(my.list), my.list)))`.

Comment: And please tell me how that solution is simpler than this: `do.call(rbind, list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2))`

Comment: `do.call(rbind, list(df1 = d1, df2 = d2))` result:
  `x   y
df1.1 1.1 4.1
df1.2 2.0 5.1
df1.3 3.5 6.3
df2.1 3.3 6.4
df2.2 2.7 5.2
df2.3 1.9 2.4
df2.4 2.9 3.0
df2.5 1.9 5.1` is not what I wanted....

Comment: I m done with this. You claimed that your question wasn't a duplicate but It clearly is. It is not a matter of what solution YOU like. That was not your initial comment. You comment was *@Sotos: This is not a duplicate, because I want to create a data frame out of a LIST. In your related question the starting points are data frames, not a list!* Have a nice day!

Comment: Well I didn't find the solution by searching for "Transform list consisting of multiple data frames"... No need to become aggressive, I think.

Comment: There's a difference between not having found something, and protesting when someone points out the question is a duplicate. The next persons that searches that will find your question and the link to the duplicate, which all the answers there. Everybody wins.

Comment: I think its not usefull to hide the answers of question by masking the questions. If I am looking for transformation of a list to a dataframe then I don't look for how to append data frames... Maybe I'm wrong, but for me the solution and the question were useful.

Comment: You are combining several data.frames into one, which is exactly what that other question was. There's no problem in that you didn't make that connection, others can help out and point you to the other question (which they did). There's just no need to rehash all the possible answers here, but we rather should just link your question to that one. That means we get to keep all the answer in one place and up to date. Future readers can still find this question with your phrasing, which will point them to the correct duplicate link. No answers are "hidden".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do this

```
do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, colour = names(my.list), my.list)))
```

Result:

```
do.call(rbind, unname(Map(cbind, colour = names(my.list), my.list)))
   colour   x   y
1   green 1.1 4.1
2   green 2.0 5.1
3   green 3.5 6.3
4    blue 3.3 6.4
5    blue 2.7 5.2
6    blue 1.9 2.4
7    blue 2.9 3.0
8    blue 1.9 5.1
9  yellow 3.4 6.2
10 yellow 2.7 5.0
11 yellow 1.8 4.1
12 yellow 0.2 0.5
```

---

Or if we are using `dplyr`, then `bind_rows` have the option `.id`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(my.list, .id = 'colour')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. How do I remove the row names?

Comment: @yPennylane  Updated the post